# How to copy specific columns of source excel sheet to specific columns of destination excel sheet?

Tags: excel

I have a source sheet that has 254 columns and another sheet which has about 800 columns. I want to copy those 254 columns to certain 254 columns ,out of 800+, of destination sheet.

For example:
source.xls has columns---

```
1.Name, 
2.DoB, 
3.Course
```

Destination.xls has columns---

```
 1.S_roll,  
 2.S_Id, 
 3.S_name,
 4.S_father_name,  
 5.S_dob,  
 6.S_course
```

As you can guess, I want to transfer ---

```
source.name to destination.s_name,
source.dob to destination.s_dob,
source.course to destination.s_course
```

Is it possible? If yes, how?
Code doesn't have to be in VBA any major language will do.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
If anyone else encounters the same thing here is my solution: https://github.com/p0int-bl4nk/ExcelProject